# firebase android double data using push

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just discovering Firebase and tried to create a small project in which save and fetch data from the database, but I have a problem in both steps, when I go to save a new object in the database I find another "parent node" I attach below the screen.

**When I go to get the data I get the null values**, and I think this problem is related to the first problem , snippet of code.

How I can fix it?

Push:

```
myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://theme.firebaseio.com/");
postRef = myFirebaseRef.child("theme");
postRef.push().setValue(theme);
```

Read data:

```
 myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         Log.v("FIREBASE","There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts");
         for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
             Theme post = postSnapshot.getValue(Theme.class);                  System.out.println(post.getCatbg() + " - chiave" );
         }
     }
     @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
         System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
     }
});
```

Theme class:

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Theme {
        private String a200;
        private String a500;
        private String a700;
        private String prim;
        private String primdark;
        private String setticon;
        private String b200;
        private String b500;
        private String b700;
        private String catbg;
        private String cattxt;
        private boolean dl;

        @JsonIgnore
        private String key;

        public Theme(){}

        public Theme(boolean defValue) {
            if(defValue) {
                String defaultColor = "#000000";
                this.a200 = defaultColor;
                this.a500 = defaultColor;
                this.a700 = defaultColor;
                this.prim = defaultColor;
                this.primdark = defaultColor;
                this.setticon = defaultColor;
                this.b200 = defaultColor;
                this.b500 = defaultColor;
                this.b700 = defaultColor;
                this.catbg = defaultColor;
                this.cattxt = defaultColor;
                this.dl = false;
            }
        }

        public Theme(String a200, String a500, String a700, String prim, String primdark, String setticon, String b200, String b500, String b700, String catbg, String cattxt, boolean dl) {
            this.a200=a200;
            this.a500=a500;
            this.a700=a700;
            this.prim=prim;
            this.primdark=primdark;
            this.setticon=setticon;
            this.b200=b200;
            this.b500=b500;
            this.b700=b700;
            this.catbg=catbg;
            this.cattxt=cattxt;
            this.dl=dl;
        }



        //Getter and setter using String

        public String getA200() {
            return a200;
        }
        public void setA200(String a200) {
            this.a200 = a200;
        }
        public String getA500() {
            return a500;
        }
        public void setA500(String a500) {
            this.a500 = a500;
        }
        public String getA700() {
            return a700;
        }
        public void setA700(String a700) {
            this.a700 = a700;
        }
        public String getPrim() {
            return prim;
        }
        public void setPrim(String prim) {
            this.prim = prim;
        }
        public String getPrimdark() {
            return primdark;
        }
        public void setPrimdark(String primdark) {
            this.primdark = primdark;
        }
        public String getSetticon() {
            return setticon;
        }
        public void setSetticon(String setticon) {
            this.setticon = setticon;
        }
        public String getB200() {
            return b200;
        }
        public void setB200(String b200) {
            this.b200 = b200;
        }
        public String getB500() {
            return b500;
        }
        public void setB500(String b500) {
            this.b500 = b500;
        }
        public String getB700() {
            return b700;
        }
        public void setB700(String b700) {
            this.b700 = b700;
        }
        public String getCatbg() {
            return catbg;
        }
        public void setCatbg(String catbg) {
            this.catbg = catbg;
        }
        public String getCattxt() {
            return cattxt;
        }
        public void setCattxt(String cattxt) {
            this.cattxt = cattxt;
        }

        public boolean getDl() {
            return dl;
        }
        public void setDl(boolean dl) {
            this.dl = dl;
        }

        //Getter and setter using int

        @JsonIgnore
        public int getA200AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(a200);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getA500AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(a500);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getA700AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(a700);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getPrimAsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(prim);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getPrimdarkAsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(primdark);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getSetticonAsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(setticon);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getB200AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(b200);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getB500AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(b500);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getB700AsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(b700);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getCatbgAsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(catbg);
        }
        @JsonIgnore public int getCattxtAsInt() {
            return Color.parseColor(cattxt);
        }
    }
```

[duplicated theme node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFi2M.png)

Json code:

```
{
  "theme" : {
    "theme" : {
      "-KCH4MaQmSylOC9VRN4k" : {
        "a200" : "f48fb1",
        "a500" : "e91e63",
        "a700" : "c2185b",
        "b200" : "242424",
        "b500" : "131313",
        "b700" : "020202",
        "catbg" : "e91e63",
        "cattxt" : "212121",
        "dl" : false,
        "prim" : "323232",
        "primdark" : "212121",
        "setticon" : "424242"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update After using myFirebaseRef instead postRef object**

```
{
  "-KCKhTfqBTkN2pMCbIs8" : {
    "test" : "7377f857-e433-4d21-a41e-1e2671f4b91b"
  },
  "-KCKhXAyczkgHWEwx3ur" : {
    "test" : "29d3753b-7352-455e-9367-a9bf2902bd36"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes sorry , added

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that `theme` ends up generating the extra level Can you share the minimal version of the `Theme` class?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes , thanks again for support  (sorry for the structure of class , is only test class)

Comment: Yikes. That's a big class. Can you see if the problem still occurs of you minimize the properties? If so, you can reduce the code that you're asking us to consider. Also pay attention to the formatting of the code you added, so that I don't have to go in and edit that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for delay , i try now with a Prova.class with only one attribute and it write correctly, but can't retrive data always null object .
I discover that i can write using myFirebaseRef object and this doesn't make another father node .

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see any reason in your code that would create an extra `theme` node. Can you once again try to isolate the problem in a minimal amount of code. It it doesn't require a custom `Theme` class, that reduces the complexity considerably.